# cancan authlogic gem's edit current user profile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Once I added the cancan Gem to my authlogic authorisation system, I started running into problems. My link_to edit current user profile died!

code:

```
#application.html.erb 

<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(:current) %>

#ApplicationController

private
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end


  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to root_url
  end

error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#edit

Couldn't find User with ID=current
```

I have tried many ways to get the current user id to the edit link nothing works has anyone have any ideas?

Regards

Dan

Comment: Maybe Rails don't know what is `:current` symbol? Also you could add some code from `UsersController` since it says that error is in this controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you want to be passing the `:current` symbol to your `edit_user_path`.  You likely want to have `edit_user_path(current_user)`.

Comment: Thanks Bensie I was at this for like 3hours, not cool!
I glad you you where there to help thanks again!!!